# Concatenate string values in one row from multiple rows with constraints SSIS / SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need some help, I'm pretty new in SSIS and have some basics in SQL Server.

I have a SQL query within a package in SSIS, I tried various solutions (`STUFF()`, `STRING_AGG()`, `SUBSTRING()`...), but every time I got some errors.

I have a file source with data that looks like this:

```
Name,Active,AccountNr,Comment
Alex,30,895478548,Food,
Alex,50,895478548,Sport,
Alex,30,5544440000,Travel,
Fabien,15,4555555,Car,
Fabien,2500,63553336,Family,
Fabien,2500,4555555,Health,
Alex,30,895478548,Travel
```

I want to add the `actives` and concatenate string values of `Comment` column (which have the same `Account` number) in one row from multiple rows

For example, rows 4-6 have the same Account number, then we should get

```
:Fabien,2515,Family/health
```

as output.

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect, as tabular text.

Comment: @GMB , i´m pretty new in the community , i've no idea how to formulate it as tabular , that´s why i´ve let it as a CSV file

Comment: That''s fine, you can also show the result in csv format. The important thing is to show the results that you want. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61602414/edit) to add that important information.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't SSIS supports `string_agg()`? If so, you can do:

```
select name, account_number, string_agg(comment, '/') all_comments
from mytable
group by name, account_number
```